# Calculate count of each status in date range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I’m using PostgreSQL and I try to realize how to build the query for calculating the count of each status of event per date in the range

#### My event table looks like:

```
| dateStart  | dateEnd    | status |
|----------------------------------|
| 2019-02-10 | 2019-02-11 | Type1  |
| 2019-02-10 | 2019-02-16 | Type1  | 
| 2019-02-10 | 2019-02-12 | Type2  |
| 2019-02-11 | 2019-02-16 | Type1  |
| 2019-02-12 | 2019-02-14 | Type2  |
| 2019-02-13 | null       | Type2  |
| 2019-02-12 | 2019-02-13 | Type2  |
| 2019-02-15 | 2019-02-16 | Type3  |
| 2019-02-14 | 2019-02-14 | Type1  |
```

Event starts from dateStart and ends by dateEnd (or null if it is still in progress) and have to be counted in every date in range if dateStart-dateEnd somehow cross query date range.

I have a date range, for example:

from: `2019-02-12`  to: `2019-02-15`

#### Actually I want to get such result for that range:

```
| date       | type1Count | type2Count | type3Count |
|---------------------------------------------------|
| 2019-02-12 | 2          | 3          | 0          | 
| 2019-02-13 | 2          | 3          | 0          | 
| 2019-02-14 | 3          | 2          | 0          | 
| 2019-02-15 | 2          | 1          | 1          |
```

#### This picture demonstrates idea:

[image: enter image option here]

#### That's what I have currently, but it only uses the dateStart

```
  SELECT DATE_TRUNC('day', "events"."dateStart") AS dateStart,
          COUNT(CASE WHEN "events"."status" = 'Type1' THEN 1 END) AS "Type1",
          COUNT(CASE WHEN "events"."status" = 'Type2' THEN 1 END) AS "Type2",
          COUNT(CASE WHEN "events"."status" = 'Type3' THEN 1 END) AS "Type3",
        FROM "events"
        GROUP BY 1
        ORDER BY 1;
```

#### I will appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method is Postgres is use to `generate_series()`:

```
select d.dte, count(e.type) as total,
       count(*) filter (where e.type = 'Type1') as type1_cnt,
       count(*) filter (where e.type = 'Type2') as type2_cnt,
       count(*) filter (where e.type = 'Type3') as type3_cnt
from (select generate_series(min(datestart), max(datestart), interval '1 day') as dte
      from events
     ) d left join
     events e
     on d.dte >= e.datestart and d.dte <= e.dateend
group by d.dte
order by d.dte;
```

Comment: Thank you, it's helped me a lot. You actually have some typos: like `order by d.te` but I successfully adapted your example for my base.